# generated report added with extra 1 hour' />

Tags: html

i have this code below as part of my entire Select option,

```
<option value="Running  Request |Running > 1 hour">Running  Request |Running > 1 hour</option>
```

everything works fine except that when i try to view the uploaded data it would have this result:

Running Request |Running > 1 hour **1 hour' />**

so the 1 hour is duplicated and would have /> in the end, im thinking it could be the **>** causing it but just cant get through it...please help

here's the thing, when i removed **>** it uploads the data and prints out Running Request |Running 1 hour fine when i query the db but when i replaced **>** or even changed it to **>** it prints out below when i query the db...i need to removed **1 hour' />**

Running Request |Running > 1 hour **1 hour' />**

Comment: where is the php? changed tag to html

Comment: can you post what is your expected output?

Comment: @bansi it should just be "Running Request |Running > 1 hour" without the excess **1 hour' />**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the > in the value

```
<option value="Running  Request |Running > 1 hour">Running  Request |Running > 1 hour</option>
```

should be

```
<option value="Running  Request |Running &gt; 1 hour">Running  Request |Running &gt; 1 hour</option>
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested but it still giving me this result when i view the uploaded data: Running Request |Running > 1 hour 1 hour' />, i wanted to eliminate this extra 1 hour' /> which is not included when i uploaded it in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

use `&#62;`

```
<option value="Running  Request |Running &gt; 1 hour">Running  Request |Running &#62; 1 hour</option>
```

best way use a scripting laguage like in php `echo ">";`

Comment: still showing Running Request |Running > 1 hour 1 hour' />, still not eliminated: **1 hour' />**